# How to render router content onto index.html in Nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js, router

I am trying to build an app that only consists of one page (frontal page) and I do all my routing within a div that is nested on main page? I am basically looking for an equivalent of  from Vue Router.

How can I change my settings so that the router is being displayed on front page and does not change the whole page by changing the url?

example code:

pages/index.vue

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="panel_container">
      <h1>Left Panel</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="panel_container">
      <h1>Middle Panel</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="panel_container"> 
      <h1>Right Panel</h1>
      <div>
        // router-view goes here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: kissu below is totally right, please do not modify `.nuxt` as it will get overwritten anyway on compile.

<strike>the solution is to organize .nuxt/layouts/default.vue in a particular way:</strike>

```html
<template>
  <YourFirstComponent />
  <Nuxt /> <!-- all routing goes here -->
  <OtherComponent />
</template>
```

<strike>this way    and    will always be present on the front page and the rest is being taken care of in</strike>

Comment: You should not touch to `.nuxt` (this one is used for caching), directly aim towards the `/layouts/default.vue` file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you do plan to have 2 things at the same time: a router to allow for components/pages change, while not updating the path.

Because if you want to not have a changing path, this is basically what an anchor is (`Table of Contents`): https://www.w3schools.in/html-tutorial/anchor/

---

If you want only the parent page, to keep identical, you need to configure some nested routes: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/file-system-routing#nested-routes

In pair with the [`nuxt-child`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/nuxt-components#the-nuxtchild-component) component, especially if aiming towards this kind of architecture

```
pages/
--| users/
-----| _id.vue
-----| index.vue
--| users.vue
```

---

Or you can also use [layouts](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/nuxt-components#the-nuxt-component), indeed. To have a single unified wrapper around all of your pages.

[image]